# How to pass the default value to a variable if None was passed?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

Can I make a default value in Pydantic if None is passed in the field?

I have the following code, but it seems to me that the validator here only works on initialization of the model and not otherwise.

**My Code:**

```
class User(BaseModel):
     name: Optional[str] = ''
     password: Optional[str] = ''
     email: EmailStr
    

    @validator('name')
    def set_name(cls, name):
        return name or 'foo'
```

**Problem Encountered:**

```
user = User(name=None, password='some_password', email='user@example.com')
print("Name is ", user.name)
# > 'Name is foo'

user.name = None
print("Name is ", user.name)
# > 'Name is None'
```

**Desired Output:**

```
user = User(name='some_name', password='some_password', email='user@example.com')
user.name = None
print("Name is ", user.name)
# > 'Name is foo'
```

Any ideas on how I can obtain the desired output? I think having getters and setters will help in tackling the issue. However, I could not get them to work in a Pydantic model:

**Attempting to implement getters and setters:**

```
class User(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str] = ''
    password: Optional[str] = ''
    email: EmailStr

    def get_password(self):
        return self.password

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password = hash_password(password)

    password = property(get_password, set_password)

user = User(name='some_name', password='some_password', email='user@example.com')
# > RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

**I also tried the property decorator:**

```
class User(BaseModel):
     name: Optional[str] = ''
     password: Optional[str] = ''
     email: EmailStr

    @property
    def password(self):
        return self._password

    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes=["bcrypt"], deprecated="auto")
        self._password = pwd_context.hash(password)

user = User(name='some_name', email='user@example.com')
user.password = 'some_password'
# > ValueError: "User" object has no field "password"
```

**I also tried overwriting the **init**:**

```
class User(BaseModel):
name: Optional[str] = ""
password: Optional[str] = ""
email: EmailStr

def __init__(self, name, password, email):
    pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes=["bcrypt"], deprecated="auto")
    password = pwd_context.hash(password)
    super().__init__(name=name, password=password, email=email)


user = User(name="some_name", password="some_password", email='user@example.com')
print(user.password)
# > AYylwSnbQgCHrl4uue6kO7yiuT20lazSzK7x # Works as expected

user.password = "some_other_password"
print(user.password)
# > "some_other_password" # Does not work

user.password = None
print(user.password)
# > None # Does not work either
```

Comment: @manas-sombre You need to use `@validator(pre=True, always=True)` and then return a default value. I used `return v or cls.__name__.lower()` to set the lowercase class name as the default value for an `Optional[str]` field.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to enable `validate_assignment` option in model config:

```
from typing import Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class User(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str] = ''
    password: Optional[str] = ''

    class Config:
        validate_assignment = True

    @validator('name')
    def set_name(cls, name):
        return name or 'foo'


user = User(name=None, password='some_password', )
print("Name is ", user.name)


user.name = None
print("Name is ", user.name)
```

```
Name is  foo
Name is  foo
```

Comment: Should a validator contain any logic to alter values? This sound like some violation of responsibilities.

Answer (score 37):

**This question asked perfectly so i wanted to provide a wider example, because there are many ways to assign a value dynamically.**

Alex's answer is correct but it only works on when the Field directly inherits a  dataclass more specifically something like this won't work.

```
class User(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str] = ""
    password: Optional[str] = ""

    class Config:
        validate_assignment = True

    @validator("name")
    def set_name(cls, name):
        return name or "bar"


user_dict = {"password": "so_secret"}
user_one = User(**user_dict)
Out: name='' password='so_secret'
```

### Validate Always

For performance reasons, by default validators are not called for fields when a value is not supplied. But situations like this when you need to set a **Dynamic Default Value** we can set that to **True**

```
class User(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str] = ""

    @validator("name", pre=True, always=True)
    def set_name(cls, name):
        return name or "bar"

In: user_one = User(name=None)
In: user_two = User()
Out: name='bar'
Out: name='bar'
```

But there is a one important catch with always, since we are using always=True pydantic would try to validate the default None which would cause an error.

Setting Pre to **`True`** it will call that field  before validation error occurs, the default of a validator pre is set to **`False`** , in which case they're called after field validation.

### Using Config

But this has some disadvantages.

```
class User(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str] = ""

    class Config:
        validate_assignment = True

    @validator("name")
    def set_name(cls, name):
        return name or "foo"

In:  user = User(name=None)
Out: name='foo'
```

When you set it to None it returns the dynamic value correctly but some situations like it is completely **`None`**, it fails.

```
In:  user = User()
Out: name=''
```

Again you need to set, to make that work.

```
pre=True
always=True
```

### Using `default_factory`

This is mostly useful in cases when you want to set a default value, like UUID or datetime etc. In that cases you might want to use **`default_factory`**, but there is a big catch you can't assign a `Callable` argument to the default_factory.

```
class User(BaseModel):
    created_at: datetime = Field(default_factory=datetime.now)

In: user = User()
Out: created_at=datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 29, 2, 40, 12, 780986)
```

Answer (score 14):

Many ways to assign a default value

**Method #1: A required `id` field with default value**

```py
class User(BaseModel):
    id: str = uuid.uuid4()
```

**Method #2 An optional `id` field with default value**

```py
class User(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[str] = uuid.uuid4()
```

**Method #3: A required `id` field with default value**

```py
class User(BaseModel):
    id: str = Field(default=uuid.uuid4())
```

**Method #4: A required `id` field with default value from callable. This is useful for generating on-demand values such as `unique UUIDs` or `Timestamps`.**
See @yagiz-degirmenci answer.

```py
class User(BaseModel):
    id: str = Field(default_factory=uuid.uuid4)  # uuid.uuid4 is not executed immediately
```

Comment: Method 4 works on the python side, but in the openapi spec FastAPI generates it sill marks the field as optional (even with the required bool in the Field)

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it in Pydantic 2 is to use `BeforeValidator()` along with `Field(default=None, validate_default=True)`

```py
IdValidator = BeforeValidator(lambda id: id or str(uuid.uuid4()))

class User(BaseModel):
    id: Annotated[str, IdValidator] = Field(default=None, validate_default=True)
```

This avoids creating a ton of `@field_validator('id', mode='before')` functions, taking up vertical space.

This is equivalent to

```py
class User(BaseModel):
    id: str = Field(default=None, validate_default=True)

    @field_validator('id', mode='before')
    @classmethod
    def ensure_id(cls, id: Optional[str]) -> str:
        return id or str(uuid.uuid4())
```

The built-in pydantic validator will check if the resulting `id` is actually a string or not, so you don't have add an `isinstance()` check